# sklearn-SVM: Define Different Loss Values for Different Classification Errors

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, svm

I have a dataset I want to classify to `4` different classes, using a multi-class SVM. However, I want to give a different weight in the loss-function to different classification errors:
If the classifier identified a `class-0` sample as a `class-3` sample or vice versa, I need a higher "cost" than any other mistake. Something like the following:

```
def weighted_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    assert (y_true >= 0) and (y_true <= 3)
    assert (y_pred >= 0) and (y_pred <= 3)
    if (abs(y_true - y_pred) == 3):
        return 2
    elif  (abs(y_true - y_pred) == 1):
        return 1
    return 0
```

I saw [sklearn's SVM class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#unbalanced-problems) has a `class-weight` parameter for the `fit` method, but I need something similar for the `loss`. Is it something we can define ourselves?

Comment: What do you mean by *but I need something similar for the loss*?

Comment: I need a `class-weight` parameter for the hinge-loss function, not for the `fit` method. Or, alternatively, a way to define my own loss function